# golang how to use double quotes properly?

Tags: go

In windows cmd console, when I use the echo command:

```
echo abc     //get: abc
echo "abc    //get: "abc 
echo "abc"   //get: "abc"
```

Then I want to run it in go language using the exec package

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd1 := "echo abc def"
    cmd2 := "echo abc\"edf"
    cmd3 := `echo abc"edf`
    cmd4 := `echo abc\"edf`
    cmd5 := "echo abcedf你好"
    fo(cmd1)
    fo(cmd2)
    fo(cmd3)
    fo(cmd4)
    fo(cmd5)
}

func fo(command string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", command)
    out, _ := cmd.Output()
    fmt.Printf("%s => %s\n", command, string(out))
}
```

I get

```
echo abc def => abc def
echo abc"edf => abc\"edf
echo abc"edf => abc\"edf
echo abc\"edf => abc\\\"edf
echo abcedf你好 => abc??edf����
```

As you can see none of them (except cmd1) is right. Also utf-8 is not showing properly. I do not want the back slash in output (I think the problem is actually in input not output, see below)

I cannot simply do something on the result (i.e. remove back slash from result), because it does not work for complex situations. For example, I want to run

```
cmd /c start "echo abc & echo def"
```

I cannot remove double quotes, otherwise the latter part will run in current window, not the start window. Then in go, below codes does not work:

```
cmd6 := "cmd /c start \"echo abc & echo def\""
fo(cmd6)
```

How to make it work in golang?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve? Is this about printing UTF-8 strings on the console or running a program with complex set of command-line arguments? I'm asking because you present a contrived example without clear (to me) goals and a moot question, so while I know something about both Go and the WIndows console, and running other programs from Go, I have no idea what *problem* to actually address. Please be more clear.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like so. I want to run cmd6 but with failures. Then I broke down to test simpler cmd1 ~  cmd5 and found cmd2~cmd5 did not work either. Forgive me if they were not the same problem. My ultimate target is to get any dos console run flawlessly (same input lead to the same output or action between dos and go), which needs all of cmd1~ cmd6 should run right just like dos console.

Answer (score 1):

What about directly using echo?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd1 := "abc def"
    cmd2 := "abc\"edf"
    cmd3 := `abc"edf`
    cmd4 := `abc\"edf`
    cmd5 := "abcedf你好"
    cmd6 := "abc & echo def"
    fo(cmd1)
    fo(cmd2)
    fo(cmd3)
    fo(cmd4)
    fo(cmd5)
    fo(cmd6)
}

func fo(command string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("echo", command)
    out, _ := cmd.Output()
    fmt.Printf("%s => %s\n", command, string(out))
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I run this on my Linux they are all right. But in windows there seems no output after each "=>". I am running windows 10.0.10586. Did you pass it through in windows?

Comment: I ran them on Mac.